# decide where to go to after connecting with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

After connecting an account with a social app using django-allauth the user is redirected to `accounts/social/connections`. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 11):

If the user is adding more social accounts to his existing (local) account, then the most logical default would be indeed to redirect to the social account connections management screen.

However, you can easily override the default by passing along a next parameter. Have a look here:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py#L125

You'll see that the `next` parameter is checked, falling back to the default (connections).

So, to change the default behavior, simply pass along a next parameter:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" next="/success/url/" %}">Google</a>
```

If you are using the default templates you'll have to add next urls here:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/socialaccount/connections.html#L53

Comment: For me `<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}" next="placetogo">`goes to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. What I am trying to achieve is redirecting users who just signed up to a special page.

Comment: If your redirect depends on certain project specific knowledge then you can use a custom adapter class (`ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`) and override the `get_login_redirect_url` method.

Comment: In the current version it's the ``get_connect_redirect_url``method.