# Could not redirect correctly when logout django

Tags: django, http, django-allauth

using django-allauth this is my setup in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  #Default: '/accounts/profile/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_URL
```

when I click to logout, login url is redirected, but after a successful login, the url page is redirected to `/accounts/login`. If page refreshes manually, home page will be redirected.

Debugging chrome shows HTTP referrer is `/account/logout` when login occurred.

I guess the referrer or session should be cleared when logging out, but somehow it isn't. How should I solve it?

Comment: are you using the redirect_to variable, which defaults to "next"

Comment: {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %} \n i've tried set next='/', but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a problem with `RedirectView` and not specified `permanent = False`

Or look at this question (second comment to answer): [decide where to go to after connecting with django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295603/decide-where-to-go-to-after-connecting-with-django-allauth)

Answer (score 0):

sorry I forgot to say i'm using JqueryMobile.  logout event seems maintain previous page headers. Add rel=""external" can solve my problem.

```
<a href="/accounts/logout" rel="external" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-user">logout</a>
```