# Django allauth Redirect after social signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, pinax

I would like to redirect to a certain link after social signup, how and where do I do that? I can do it for regular signup but I can't for social signup.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can write your own custom [social account adapter](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects) to handle different logged in redirection from different social accounts and not messing with your normal account settings, like so:

```
# adapter.py    
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        # do your logic here for different social accounts
        ...
        return 'url/to/your/redirection' # or reverse(view) or whatever

# settings.py
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "point.to.adaptor.SocialAccountAdapter"
```

#### Edited:

In case you want to alter the redirection for newly signed up, you may customise adapter's **save_user** method:

```
class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    ...
    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        super(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, sociallogin, form=form)
        # your logic here... and return redirection afterward
        return redirect(...)
```

Comment: but this will make it redirect to this link after login too right? I want it to redirect after signup ONLY so that the user can complete his profile (the fields that aren't required in signup)

Comment: @EbtessamZoheir, I've edited my answer according to your requirements. Please check if this works (I haven't tested yet)

Answer (score 2):

After both social and normal it should be redirecting to your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings. Do you have that set?

Theres also some good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295603/decide-where-to-go-to-after-connecting-with-django-allauth) about custom redirection

Comment: but this will make it redirect to this link after login too right? I want it to redirect after signup only so that the user can complete his profile (the fields that aren't required in signup).

Comment: Yes, do you have your LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL set to that url? /accounts/profile/ or where you have the edit profile?