# Django allauth Redirect to email verification after social signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I use Twitter for main signup/login and I would like to redirect to 'accounts/email' link after social signup because I want to force new user to provide their emails. I've found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759407/django-allauth-redirect-after-social-signup) and answer from [@Anzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3849456/anzel)

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
      def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
          super(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, sociallogin, form=form)
          return redirect('/accounts/email/')
```

but the answer didn't work for me and got this

```
AttributeError at /accounts/twitter/login/callback/

'super' object has no attribute 'save_user'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/twitter/login/callback/?oauth_token=HSowSgAAAAAAuTblAAABVrLCOpE&oauth_verifier=cVrwyB2Vfk2Lgsrwg5fqE0wyzrfnwJ3H
Django Version:     1.9.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'super' object has no attribute 'save_user'
```

Comment: Try `super(SocialAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, sociallogin, form=form)` instead of `super(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, sociallogin, form=form)`. I.e., call `super` on `SocialAccountAdapter` instead of `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`

Comment: I did it and the error disapear, the problem is that it allways redirects to the verification email url even for existing user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In setting.py I only add those two lines and forgot about the adapter :

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

and now after signup or login it redircts new users only to  /accounts/social/signup/ and this view actually force the user to submit his eamil and process to a verification.

Answer (score 1):

add this code in api/**init**.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def social_signed_up(request, user, **kwargs):
    
    social_account = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=user).first()

    if social_account:
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(
            redirect("https://example.com/foo/")
        )
```